# Importing CSV Data and formatting in Excel via Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, xlsx

I am importing CSV based data in an Excel spreadsheet via Python. I would like to know if it is possible to import the data and divide it in several columns (like we would do via the importing menu under DATA in Excel).

So far, I convert my CSV to a pandas and imported it in Excel, but all my data is clustered in 1 column :

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Contractuel\Desktop\Test\Candiac_TypeLum_UTF8.csv')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('TypeLum_TEST.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read_csv method takes an argument `sep=` which tells pandas what separates the data. You probably need to use this to specify what the separator in the CSV file is. Default is `,` but CSVs sometimes have `;` or other things as separators.